# Use XPath to return full text inside tags

Tags: xml, xpath

I have some data returned from wireshark that looks like this

```
<packets>
  <packet>
    <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="302">
    ...
  <packet>
  <packet>
    .....
  </packet>
<packets>
```

I would like to write an XPath expression that returns the entire contents of the packet tags back into the language I am using. The alternative would be to return a single packet based on a filter. The key thing is that I want the entire contents of the packet tags as an XML string returned, from what I can see xpath only returns single node values?

Comment: What do you mean by the "entire contents" of an element? What do you mean by "XML string"? What should the result look like? What is the "language you are using"?

Comment: No, XPath does not only return single node values.  `//packet` will, for example, select all `packet elements.  You may be being surprised by a return of only the first value, possibly converted to a string, but as @MathiasMüller mentioned, you'll have to explain your question further for us to be able to help.  Thanks.

Comment: The language I am using is called iTest, it's for router/network testing. I'm thinking the issue is in iTest. If I use an XPath expression of `//packet` it will return 2 values but they will be empty. What I want is an array returned that contains each packet as an XML string. Eg array should look like this `packets[0] = <packet>....</packet>`

Comment: I'm now thinking that XPath is returning a collection of packet objects to my language and it doesn't know what to do with it, ie the language is just expecting single values. Is there any way to get XPath to return the contents of the packet as a string instead. I'm thinking this isn't possible.

Comment: If you got back `<packet>....</packet>` as XML, what would you do with it in this iTest language?  Re-parse it?  I suspect you ought to back up, reconsider your true goal, and void the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234215).  Good luck.

Comment: Yes I would re-parse it. It would be useful to get out the packet I am interested in first and then perform a number of xpath expressions on that packet. This avoids implementing the logic to find the packet multiple times. With regards the XY problem I had considered that. The only solution I can come up with that works in the current environment is regex.

Comment: What you're describing would be trivial with XSLT or even Python/Java/C#/etc coupled with an XPath library.   With "iTest", can't say.  Sorry.